# What is the probability that a randomly selected point is closer to the center than to the edge?

Tags: probability, statistics

I was working on a problem from the classic book "Frequently Asked Questions in Quantitative Finance" by Paul Wilmott: You have a square and a random variable that picks a random point on the square with a uniform distribution. What is the probability that a randomly selected point is closer to the center than to the edge?

Here are the provided solution: Many people will think that the required probability is the same as the probability of landing in a circle with a diameter half the side of the square. But this is not the case. The line separating closer to the center from closer to the edge is a parabola. The answer is
$$(-1 + \sqrt{2})^2 + \frac{2}{3}(3 - 2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

I am really confused and wonder how one should approach this problem.

Comment: There would be a bunch of cases about which edge a point in the square is closest to, but you can simplify these cases by splitting the square into four equivalent triangles (by drawing the diagonals). Since the triangles are all the same, the probability you're asking for would be exactly the same as the probability that a point in a 45-45-90 triangle is closer to the right-angle vertex than the hypotenuse.

Comment: In higher dimensions (so a hypercube),  the probability that a randomly selected point is closer to the centre than to the outside declines towards $0$ as the number of dimensions increases, but the probability that a randomly selected point is closer to the centre than to the nearest vertex stays at $\frac12$

Answer (score 3):

Consider this figure and the central region:

[image]

See dashed lines for integral:

$$A = 8 \int\limits_{x=0}^{1/4} \min[x, \sqrt{1/4-x}] \ dx = \frac{1}{3} \left(4 \sqrt{2}-5\right) \approx 0.218951$$

which matches the OP's answer.